# Replace all components of a kit product in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am new to Netsuite,
I have several kit product, each kit products have different number of components.
I want to replace all components of a kit product with one  components in Netsuite.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CSV import update option.

Comment: I tried , csv import, update with  OVERWRITE SUBLISTS checkbox checked.I am unable to overwrite the existing components with on one dummy component , Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To replace existing components, You need to replace the component items with new items and assign the line of the new item to be equal to that of the old item. In so doing, it will overwrite the component instead of appending to the components.